# How to generate service .class files in rosjava?

Tags: rosservice, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new to ros and rosjava. I am going through basic tutrials of ros and rosjava. I have followed below steps.

1. Created a rosjava pakage.

   > mkdir -p myjava/src
   > cd myjava/src
   > catkin_create_rosjava_pkg testpkg1
   > cd ..
   > catkin_make
   > source devel/setup.bash
   > Then created rosjava project inside this package

   > cd rosjava_catkin_package_a
   > catkin_create_rosjava_project subproject1
   > cd ../..
   > catkin_make
   > So now I have testpkg1 inside which is java project subproject1. I want to try my own service example given in tutorials. So I created msg folder and srv folder inside my package testpkg1 but outside project subproject1.
   > Inside the msg and srv are my .msg and .srv files respectivey. Structure below.

   testpkg1

   > msg
   > >Num.msg
   > srv
   > >AddSum.srv
   > subproject1
   > package.xml,CmakeList.txt,gradlew,build.gradle etc

I made below changes in package.xml

```
 <build_depend>message_generation</build_depend>
 <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
 <run_depend>message_runtime</run_depend>
 <run_depend>std_msgs</run_depend>
```

I made changes in CMakeList.txt

```
find_package(CATKIN REQUIRED std_msgs message_generation)
add_message_file(
DIRECTORY msg
Files
Num.msg
 )
 add_Service_files(
 DIRECTORY srv
 Files
 AddSum.srv
 )
 generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES std_msgs)
catkin_package(DEPENDENCIES message_runtime std_msgs)
```

I didnot make any changes to build.gradle. After sourcing I am trying catkin_make. The build gets succeeded however I only see AddSum.h files, AddSumRequest.h, AddSumResponse.h and same, .py ,.js,.lisp files I am not able to see any .java files for same and .class files too. Should this files get generated in this same step or am I missing something? i have also tried

```
genjava_message_artifacts --verbose - p testpkg1
```

but it is still not generating any java related files.. I do see the .class files for Listener and Talker but not for AddSum srv.

Any help will appreciated! Thanks..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256649/how-to-generate-service-.class-files-in-rosjava?/) by [ysg](https://answers.ros.org/users/29621/ysg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-03-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jubeira](https://answers.ros.org/users/29146/jubeira/) on 2017-09-27**:
At a first glance I can't see what's wrong with the code. I guess that if you could create the rosjava pkg you have the build tools sourced. Have you found a solution?
Take a look at this commit for reference: https://github.com/jubeira/tango_ros/commit/fb7933275b6eab5a671b43f28b3d03ab8a7d1ad6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While the tutorial is built, this issue can be used as a reference: https://github.com/rosjava/android_core/issues/277.

Note that generating new messages and services is not related with rosjava in particular: the mechanism is the same used for regular ROS, but adding the Java generators. That can be done, for example, installing rosjava from source and sourcing the workspace. Then, using `catkin_make` on a package will also generate the `.class` artifacts for that package.

Also, see this example using services: https://github.com/jubeira/rosjava_srv_test.

EDIT: see http://wiki.ros.org/rosjava_build_tools/Tutorials/indigo/UsingServices

---

Originally posted by [jubeira](https://answers.ros.org/users/29146/jubeira/) with karma: 1054 on 2017-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0